# R Shiny: How to build a function to create many similar renderUI pickers in R?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, picker

I am working on a project which requires many pickers that essentially do the same thing. I cannot use the same renderUI output multiple times in a Shiny Dashboard, so I have ended up copy, pasting, and changing small things (such as variable names) to overcome this. However, the code for my dashboard is now approaching over a thousand lines, and I would like to simplify this process with a function in which I can pass in arguments and output a unique renderUI object. Below is an example of similar renderUI pickers I have created:

```
# Region Picker
output$picker_Region_Map <- renderUI({
  ls_regions_map <- df_raw %>%
    distinct(Region) %>%
    pull()
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "mapRegion"
    , label = "Region"
    , choices = ls_regions_map 
    , multiple = TRUE
    , selected = ls_regions_map
    , options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))  
}) #renderUI End

# Campus Picker
output$picker_Campus_Map <- renderUI({
  ls_campus_map <- df_raw %>%
    filter(Region %in% input$mapRegion) %>%
    distinct(Campus) %>%
    pull()
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "mapCampus"
    , label = "Campus" 
    , choices = ls_campus_map
    , multiple = TRUE
    , selected = ls_campus_map
    , options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) 
}) #renderUI End
```

and

```
# Region Picker
output$picker_Region<- renderUI({
  ls_regions <- df_raw %>%
    distinct(Region) %>%
    pull()
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "inRegion"
    , label = "Region"
    , choices = ls_regions 
    , multiple = TRUE
    , selected = ls_regions 
    , options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
}) #renderUI End

# Campus Picker
output$picker_Campus <- renderUI({
  ls_campus <- df_raw %>%
    filter(Region %in% input$inRegion) %>%
    distinct(Campus) %>%
    pull()
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "inCampus"
    , label = "Campus" 
    , choices = ls_campus
    , multiple = TRUE
    , selected = ls_campus
    , options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
}) #renderUI End
```

Has anyone had this experience before? Any suggestions?

This is my first question on the site, so if anything is not correctly formatted or does not follow the guidelines/ ettiquet, please let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome!  I don't think your problem is with renderUI. That part is somewhat unavoidable. You just need some abstraction to cut down on the amount of code. For starters, Write you're own `standardPicker` function, that just wraps `pickerInput` and uses your defaults like `standardPicker <- function(.inputId, .label, .choices) { pickerInput(inputId = .inputId, label = .label, choices = .choices, selected = .choices, multiple = T, options = list('actions-box' = TRUE))}`

Comment: Also, it seems like at least some of the pickers do not need to be rendered by the server. You can put those directly  on your UI.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Thanks for the advice! I will create that standardPicker function. In regards to the follow up comment, how do you distinguish between pickers that would have to be rendered by the server? For instance, some of them rely on reactive data tables. Does the reliance on reactive data tables affect the choice? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all.  In your first picker `output$picker_Region_Map` for example, I can see that nothing is reactive.  There's no `input` and no other reactives.  You could prepare `ls_regions_map ` in your global script, then it would be available to all sessions.  On the contrary, your campus picker needs to be rendered from the server, since it needs to react to input changes.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Gotcha. Most pickers rely on reactive data, so could the standardPicker function be edited to work within the server?

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Awesome! Thank you so much for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I might start to  refactor the campus picker.

This would appear in my global script:

```
standardPicker <- function(.inputId, .label, .choices) { 
    pickerInput(inputId = .inputId, label = .label, choices = .choices, 
        selected = .choices, multiple = T, options = list('actions-box' = TRUE))
 }
```

This would appear in my server:

```
ls_campus <- reactive({
    df_raw %>%
    filter(Region %in% input$inRegion) %>%
    distinct(Campus) %>%
    pull()
 })

 output$picker_Campus <- renderUI(standardPicker('inCampus','Campus',ls_campus())
```